# How to display linked item's fields with rendering variants using SXA?

Tags: sxa

I've created a custom template that links to the author of an article that I'm publishing. Whenever I render that variant, I get the Sitecore Item ID instead of the text of that link. I'd like to do this without any coding (I'm trying to use SXA as much as I can OOB), but if there's not a way, then a coded solution would be OK. Here's how my Author field is setup:
[image: Author Configuration]

Here's my Variant Configuration:
[image: Variant Configuration]

Here's what the rendered version looks like:
[image: Variant Display]

What do I need to do in order to display the sitecore item instead of the ID?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because your **Author** field (defined on a page template) is a *link* type and what you are displaying right now is a raw field value (which in your case is a guid).

This is normal and expected. To fulfil your requirements you need to create so called 'pass through field' or field reference.

Instead of creating `VariantField` with **Author** value in `FieldName` field, create a `VariantReference` with **Author** value in `PassThroughField` field.

Then underneath create the variant structure to display fields from linked author item.

Your variant definition item could look like this.

[image]

**To summarize**

`Title` and `Image` under variant definition node displays fields from the page you are currently on but `Name`, `Profile Picture`, `Short Bio` displays fields from different item (linked author item).