# SXA Image as link with link description as title attribute using Rendering Variants

Tags: sxa

I have an SXA Image component that is a link, but the title attribute value of the link is the image name.

I want to pass the link description to the title attribute using rendering variants.
What i have
[image]

And the result when hovering with the mouse is: 
[image]

Is the any way of having the link descripton instead of having the image name ?

For example:

[image]

[image]

Right now the Html result is this:

```
<div class="component-content">
 <a class="field-image"></a><a title="Image 11" 
  href="https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2569/how-to-display- 
  linked-items-fields-with-rendering-variants-using-sxa"><img 
  src="/-/media/images/solutions/insurance/insurance-screenshot-create- 
  brilliant-digital-experience-v3.png?     
h=379&amp;la=en&amp;w=472&amp;hash=17057797BD81175CCF876F4C04DC59A6B9216463" 
  alt="" width="472" height="379" data-variantitemid="{E2A5B62B-C38B-4FF6- 
  948C-8243CE9E65AD}" data-variantfieldname="Image" style="margin: 0px 0px">
 </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Try to set `Alt` field on Image. That should do the trick!

Comment: @PeterProcházka filling the Alternative Text field on image didn't made any change

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Alternate text` on the `Link` field, not the image. The `Link Description` will set the text of the link if it has text, but you are using an image, so that will replace the text. The `Title` attribute is set by the `Alternate text` field:

[image: Set the <code>Alternate text</code> field]

Comment: That won't work either

Comment: This is not working , is there a workaround for this ?